# PySide2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyside, pyside2

Has anyone had any luck installing PySide2 on a raspberry Pi?

Have tried nearly every solution provided on the internet with no luck:

```
pip3 install PySide2
```

and the solution provided by: https://forum.qt.io/topic/112813/installing-pyside2-on-raspberry-pi

But none seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You will have to manually compile PySide2 and unfortunately that is usually difficult if you are a beginner, if you only want to use Qt with python on raspberry then you can use PyQt5: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 python-pyqt5`

Comment: I tried those instructions, and got PySide2 to install.   Did you get any error messages?  I've been able to run some basic tests, which match some working example on a Windows system.  The problem I've got is that I can't run pyside2-uic, which converts a .ui file (built on a Windows machine) to .py (I believe this is for python2), and I can't run qt designer.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install python3-pyside2.qt3dcore python3-pyside2.qt3dinput python3-pyside2.qt3dlogic python3-pyside2.qt3drender python3-pyside2.qtcharts python3-pyside2.qtconcurrent python3-pyside2.qtcore python3-pyside2.qtgui python3-pyside2.qthelp python3-pyside2.qtlocation python3-pyside2.qtmultimedia python3-pyside2.qtmultimediawidgets python3-pyside2.qtnetwork python3-pyside2.qtopengl python3-pyside2.qtpositioning python3-pyside2.qtprintsupport python3-pyside2.qtqml python3-pyside2.qtquick python3-pyside2.qtquickwidgets python3-pyside2.qtscript python3-pyside2.qtscripttools python3-pyside2.qtsensors python3-pyside2.qtsql python3-pyside2.qtsvg python3-pyside2.qttest python3-pyside2.qttexttospeech python3-pyside2.qtuitools python3-pyside2.qtwebchannel python3-pyside2.qtwebsockets python3-pyside2.qtwidgets python3-pyside2.qtx11extras python3-pyside2.qtxml python3-pyside2.qtxmlpatterns python3-pyside2uic

got from here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/112813/installing-pyside2-on-raspberry-pi/6